# Get User Information using Access Token in Microsoft graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

My application wants to access all users' mailboxes. For that, I am getting permission from Admin consent. Now I want to get the user details of the admin who consented to the application. I know we can't use Me context ('**/me**' `API end-point`) as we are getting consent without a signed-in user.

**Is there any way by which we can get user details of the admin who consented to our application using the `access token`?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the id of the user?

Comment: No, we don't have a user id. We need the user details of the admin who consented to the application. Please note I am using the application permissions only.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, the access token does not contain user details of the admin who consented to your application. One way to get this information is by [viewing activity reports in the Azure portal.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-find-activity-reports) You might also consider working with the [activity reports API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/azure-ad-auditlog-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) provided by Microsoft Graph.

Please let me know whether this helps and if you have further questions.

Comment: I believe it won't work in my case. It is just a simple application to read and write events to the user's calendar within the organization. In this, I just have to show who consented to the application.